# Oracle 11g not supporting JDK 1.7

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am using Tomcat server 8

I have added Ojdbc7.jar in Lib

and using Oracle 11g (11.2.0.2) version

My code is :

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.sql.*;

public class PrintForm extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        //Variables declaration
        String emp_name = req.getParameter("name");
        String s = "INSERT into Emp values(?,?)";

        try{
            //Making connection with Oracle

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

            //Inserting data into table
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(s);
            pst.setInt(1,1);
            pst.setString(2,emp_name);
            pst.executeUpdate();

            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }       
    }
}
```

And this is throwing ,

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

this exception.

So what driver, or what JDK version I should use ?
current version is 1.7

Comment: You should go through the JDBC basics tutorial.  This is covered in the first lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` line before the `Connection con = D....`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to add, because as in JDK 1.8 it is no more supported, so I forgot to add it in 1.7

Comment: @MagentoDeveloper You're wrong, this works the same in Java 8. The problem is probably that you deployed the driver with the application and not in the tomcat `lib` folder. In that case JDBC 4 automatic driver loading (introduced in Java 6) won't work and you will need to load the driver manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should to load your driver first before you create your connection :

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", 
                 "system", "oracle");
```

You can find a good tutorial about that here : [Connect to Oracle DB via JDBC driver](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03)

- If you are using Oracle 11.2 or 11gR2 with Java 8, 7 or 6 then you should use ojdbc6.jar.  (The caveat is that JDK7 and JDK8 are supported in 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4 only.)
- If you are using Oracle 11.2 or 11gR2 with Java 5 then you should use ojdbc5.jar.
- If you are using Oracle 12.1 or 12cR1 with Java 7 and 8 then you should use ojdbc7.jar
- If you are using Oracle 12.1 or 12cR1 with Java 6 then you should use ojdbc6.jar
- If you are using Oracle 12.2 or 12cR2 with Java 8 then you should use ojdbc8.jar.
- If you are using Oracle 18.3 with Java 8 through 11 then you should use ojdbc8.jar.

The following have been removed from the FAQ because Oracle 11.1 and earlier are no longer supported except under the "Sustaining Support" program:

- If you are using Oracle 11gR1 with Java 6, then you should use ojdbc6.jar.
- If you are using Oracle 11gR1 with Java 5, then you should use ojdbc5.jar.

---

You are using 11gR2, so you need ojdbc6.jar, but note the caveat about the Oracle DB versions that support Java 7 and Java 8.

It is also advisable to use the most recent version of Java that is compatible with your version of Oracle DB; i.e. Java 8.  (Java 7 and earlier are past their "end of life" ... unless you have an Oracle Java support contract.)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to register the driver

```
  DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
```

Please read the javadocs of the oracle driver. There it explains this and how to get a connection in different scenarios: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

Also, if you search online for the error `No suitable driver found for` you'll find plenty of sites explaining how to fix this issue  in this scenario (and others).

Comment: I have done changes, as per your suggestion, but same exception is there, I am uploading full code, you can check it.